# Wordpress - Translate a string within javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Im trying to translate this string in javascript but i cant seem to do it properly.

```
$(".search-overlay .s").attr("placeholder", "Type here to search");
```

Ive tried the following but it gives errors, any ideas ?

```
$(".search-overlay .s").attr("placeholder", "<?php _e( '"Type here to search"', 'romeo' ); ?>");
```

Thanks.

Comment: **`Question Title !== Question Code`**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "translate" here?

Comment: I'm guessing you're on Wordpress and trying to use its [_e](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_e/) function within a placeholder? What errors are you getting? And why the double quotes on `'"Type here to search"'`?

Comment: Sorry yes thats correct, the page just hangs, doesnt give me an error as such, just a blank white screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this proper Wordpress way by using wp_localize_script() function

Please check this codex page out:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script

Basically in php:

```
// Register the script
wp_register_script( 'some_handle', 'path/to/myscript.js' );

// Localize the script with new data
$translation_array = array(
    'some_string' => __( 'Some string to translate', 'plugin-domain' ),
    'a_value' => '10'
);
wp_localize_script( 'some_handle', 'object_name', $translation_array );

// Enqueued script with localized data.
wp_enqueue_script( 'some_handle' );
```

And in javascript:

```
alert(object_name.some_string);
```